# Function to implement SVM Matlab

Tags: matlab, svm

I have to implement an SVM classifier that recognizes labels.
The code is that:

```
function[Y_SVM_test] = getSVM(x,y,z, labels)

%matrix that contain x,y,z
X = [];

%vector of labels
Y = [];

X = [X; x y z];
Y = [Y; labels];

cv = cvpartition(length(X),'holdout',0.2);

% Training set 
Xtrain = X(training(cv),:);
Ytrain = Y(training(cv));


% Test set
Xtest = X(test(cv),:);
Ytest = Y(test(cv));

tic
mySVM = fitcecoc(Xtrain,Ytrain);
toc

Y_SVM_test = predict(mySVM,Xtest);

end
```

With the function `fitcecoc` the execution never ends, I used it incorrectly? I tried to use also the function `fitcsvm`, which seems more specific from the documentation, but the error I get is the following: `Error using ClassificationSVM.prepareData (line 686) You can not train an SVM model for more than 2 classes.`
In general I have not understood well what is the best way to run SVM in Matlab. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good to me. When you say it never ends, I would guess you just haven't waited long enough. If your dataset is fairly large, fitting an ECOC SVM model can take a long time.

Using `fitcecoc` is the right way to fit a multiclass SVM model. SVMs by themselves are only a two-class model, which is fitted by `fitcsvm`. To fit a multiclass model, a wrapper is needed. ECOC is such a wrapper - what it does it to take each class, and separately fit a two-class model for that class against all the others. That's why it can take so long - it needs to fit multiple models, one for each class.

PS: you don't need `X = [];` and then `X = [X; x y z];`. Just say `X = [x y z]`, it has the same effect. Similarly, just say `Y = labels`.